# Why Web Api include properties in response that are not projected

Tags: entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2

I have a view model

```
public class MyViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Position { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Office { get; set; }
        public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
        public int? Age { get; set; }
        public int? Salary { get; set; }
        public int? Extn { get; set; }
    }
```

And I am doing projection on my entity

```
 public List<ViewModel.StaffViewModel> GetAll()
        {
            var context = new GistDemoDbEntities();

            var model = context.Staff
                .Select(s => new ViewModel.StaffViewModel
                {
                    FirstName = s.FirstName,
                    LastName = s.LastName,
                    Position = s.Position,
                    Salary = s.Salary
                }).ToList();

            return model;
        }
```

And use Web Api to return back as json, but in reponse I found out it includes other properties as well that define in the View Model with vlaue null. I only want to have those properties that I need in reponse, how is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

- Remove them from your ViewModel, a view model should only conta9in
  what you intend to use anyway.

or

- Use [JsonIgnore] on your properties to prevent JSON.Net from mapping
  them.

Json Ignore is an attribute, look here;

http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/SerializationAttributes.htm

Comment: Actually I do want some properties to expose in one of my view whereas on other view I want all of them. That's why I created a View Model which contain all properties. Is there anyway, I can only show projected entities in response?

Comment: Create another view model with only the properties you need.